# Activity crash when open external url

Tags: android

I have an activity that opens another activity and in this I can not make the code run to open an external URL in android Studio. 
The app breaks...
I used the internet permission.

code:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.br"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Do I need to create another JavaClass to enter these codes, or can I use it in MainActivity java?

**Logcat**

> ```
> Process: br.com.vinnydantas.curriculo, PID: 3355
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Linkedin(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'imageLinkedin'
>     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4479)
>     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4443)
>     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
> ```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Did not solve , i tried

Comment: share your logcat trace.

Comment: I feel there is nothing wrong with your onClick(). Kindly check is there any ImageView with id `imageLinkedin` actually present in your layout or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call like this

```
public static void openBrowser(final Context context, String url) {

 if (!url.startsWith(HTTP) && !url.startsWith(HTTPS)) {
        url = HTTP + url;
 }

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose browser"));// Choose browser is arbitrary :)
}
```

Comment: app has stopped , ty

Comment: Please try updated answer , i have try here it is working

Comment: thx, I solved the problem, I was putting the code in the wrong place.